# Array[key] of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello i wonder if it's passible to push object into array with some key
i mean by that

```
arra = [];
arra.push({
    'test1a': 'trtrtrt',
    'test13a': 'trtrtrt',
    'test14a': 'trtrtrt',
})
arra.push({
    'test1a': 'trtrtrt',
    'test13a': 'trtrtrt',
    'test14a': 'trtrtrt',
})
arra['ddd'] = [];
arra['ddd'] = ({
    'test1d': 'trtrtrt',
    'test13d': 'trtrtrt',
    'test14d': 'trtrtrt',
})
arra['ddd'].push({
    'test1f': 'trtrtrt',
    'test13f': 'trtrtrt',
    'test14f': 'trtrtrt',
})
```

node error when i'm trying to do that 
[image: nodejs error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After assigning the array, you have to push to it instead of overwriting it:

```
arra['ddd'] = [];
arra['ddd'].push({
    'test1d': 'trtrtrt',
    'test13d': 'trtrtrt',
    'test14d': 'trtrtrt',
})
arra['ddd'].push({
    'test1f': 'trtrtrt',
    'test13f': 'trtrtrt',
    'test14f': 'trtrtrt',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
arra['ddd'].push({
    'test1f': 'trtrtrt',
    'test13f': 'trtrtrt',
    'test14f': 'trtrtrt',
})
```

It adds items to js object. Then you can use it by typeing `arra['ddd']['test1d']` or `arra.ddd.test1d`.

Answer (score 0):

Put anything into an array using Array.push()

```
var a=["Array Element"], b={"name": "MyObjName" };
a.push(b);    
// O/p : Array Element,[object Object]
```

now, you want to access name of b den you do this :

```
 var a=["Array Element"], b={"name": "MyObjName" };
 a.push(b.name);    
 // O/p : Array Element,MyObjName
```

Likewise , if you have key :

```
   var a=["Array Element"], b={"abc" :{"name": "MyObjName"} };
   a.push(b.abc.name);  
 // O/p : Array Element,MyObjName
```